# gdb - how to call memset for the array of pointers

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, memset

I debug an example program which defines the array of pointers:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int* t[] = {&a, &b, &c};
```

I would like to set all pointers in the array to NULL during debugging. When I use the following command:

```
call memset(t, 0x0, sizeof(int*)*3)
```

I get this output:

```
$3 = (void *(*)(void *, int, size_t)) 0x7ffff77e7e10 <__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms>
```

When I print the array pointers are not set to NULL:

```
(gdb) print t
$4 = {0x7fffffffddc0, 0x7fffffffddc4, 0x7fffffffddc8}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: sizeof((int*)*3) or sizeof(int*)*3?

Comment: What version of GDB are you using? It looks like it’s accidentally calling an IFUNC resolver function.

Comment: @zubergu - of course `sizeof(int*) * 3`, updated.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick gdb ver. 8,1.1 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get this output:

You get this output because in your version of GLIBC `memset` is a [GNU indirect function](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC). It doesn't write any memory, it returns an address of the actual implementation (`__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms` in your case).

You can verify that this is the case:

```
$ readelf -Ws /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep ' memset'
  1233: 00000000000b2df0   241 IFUNC   GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 memset@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   557: 00000000000b2df0   241 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 memset_ifunc
  6000: 00000000000b2df0   241 IFUNC   GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 memset
```

To actually set the memory, you need to call the *implementation* function, such as `__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms`.

P.S. To `memset` an array of 3 pointers, it's easier to simply set each one individually: `(gdb) t[0]=0`. But I assume the object you actually want to zero out is larger.

For ease of debugging, you may write a trivial `local_memset()` and call *it* instead.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Employed Russian's answer, insert `()` and use

```
 call memset()(t, 0x0, sizeof(int*)*3)
```

That works because `memset()` returns the function you actually want to call.